# Why is this section of my site having a white background?

Tags: html, css, background

I am working on a personal site, and every single section looks fine, but one is not getting the background color I want it to be. The bottom section, right above the about section (Opia Section) is the problem. The website is [Here](http://kingpixil.github.io/kabir/). 
You can find the code at [this github repo.](https://github.com/KingPixil/kabir) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's the section with id `#rileyscycles`. It simply doesn't have a background defined for it - it has settings for `background-position`, `background-size` and `background-repeat`, but no `background`, `background-image` or `background-color`

And none of its parent elements has a background that this section could inherit.

EDIT: As Dr Manish Joshi wrote: If you remove the "#" from the ID name, it finds the obviously intended CSS rule and is displayed with a background.

Answer (score 1):

In index page, around line number 160,

```
 <section id="specialized" class="spechover"> // Line no. around 126
                <div class="info">
                <div class="text">

 <section id="volcom" class="rileyshover"> // Line no. 147
                <div class="info">
                <div class="text">

 <section id="#rileyscycles" class="rileyshover"> //Line no. 160
                <div class="info">
                <div class="text">
```

There is # used in id while not used on other sections...so on line 160, try removing "#" in id.